# Pure Front end JavaScript with Web API versus MVC views with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This was more a discussion for what peoples thoughts are these days on how to split a web application.

I am used to creating an MVC application with all its views and controllers. I would normally create a full view and pass this back to the browser on a full page request, unless there were specific areas that I did not want to populate straight away and would then use DOM page load events to call the server to load other areas using AJAX.

Also, when it came to partial page refreshing, I would call an MVC action method which would return the HTML fragment which I could then use to populate parts of the page. This would be for areas that I did not want to slow down initial page load, or areas that fitted better with AJAX calls. One example would be for table paging. If you want to move on to the next page, I would prefer it if an AJAX call got that info rather than using a full page refresh. But the AJAX call would still return an HTML fragment.

My question is. Are my thoughts on this archaic because I come from a .net background rather than a pure front end background?

An intelligent front end developer that I work with, prefers to do more or less nothing in the MVC views, and would rather do everything on the front end. Right down to web API calls populating the page. So that rather than calling an MVC action method, which returns HTML, he would prefer to return a standard object and use javascript to create all the elements of the page.

The front end developer way means that any benefits that I normally get with MVC model validation, including client side validation, would be gone. It also means that any benefits that I get with creating the views, with strongly typed html templates etc would be gone.

I believe this would mean I would need to write the same validation for front end and back end validation. The javascript would also need to have lots of methods for creating all the different parts of the DOM. For example, when adding a new row to a table, I would normally use the MVC partial view for creating the row, and then return this as part of the AJAX call, which then gets injected into the table. By using a pure front end way, the javascript would would take in an object (for, say, a product) for the row from the api call, and then create a row from that object. Creating each individual part of the table row.

The website in question will have lots of different areas, from administration, forms, product searching etc. A website that I don't think requires to be architected in a single page application way.

What are everyone's thoughts on this?

I am interested to hear from front end devs and back end devs.

UPDATE

Following on from a suggestion, I have created a thread in programmers stack exchange for the discussion.

[Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/pure-front-end-javascript-with-web-api-versus-mvc-views-with-ajax)

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript MVVM frameworks? Like Knockoutjs or Angular. You can have the best of both worlds: a data-binding framework for frontend and a MVC framework on the backend. I'd always rather return JSON data than HTML fragments.

Comment: I know about KnockoutJS and AngularJS, however I have never used them. And according to the front end developer, he only wishes to use them if we have the need. Why is it you prefer to return JSON rather than HTML? Honest question.

Comment: This seems more like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, since there isn't a right answer to your question.

Comment: To be honest, I did not know about that website :S thanks. I have posted it there instead.

Comment: Server resources are expensive, and the more you can do in the client the more distributed your application becomes.  Also, the less your server does, the less dependent you are on a specific server tech.  My servers perform auth, model validation, and return json.  I use web-api, but any server tech can do this and I can switch pretty easily.  Client side, I use Angular because it's easy to understand among my team, and too many more benefits to fit in comments.  The benefits outweigh the added library.

Answer (score 0):

> The front end developer way means that any benefits that I normally
>   get with MVC model validation, including client side validation, would
>   be gone

No, not necessarily. You can do Model Validation in Web Api too, please follow this [reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).

> My question is. Are my thoughts on this archaic because I come from a
>   .net background rather than a pure front end background?

Having Web API instead of MVC controller would benefit in writing different platform applications ranging from Mobile, tablets, Desktop, Web etc. So this decisions depends on how many devices you are going to support and what are the other different applications which are dependent on your data.

Also also returning objects (especially JSON) would be light weight and highly scalable than returning HTML.

One more advantage of going to Web API is that it is purely HTTP and there is no need to play with Razor. Using Web API, you can complete the end to end application using HTML, JQuery and C# combo rather than writing a lot of razor code.

Comment: Ok I see your point with the model validation. However, the point still stands. I would deal with model validation server side as I am used to for teh web api call, but then the client side would need to duplicate this effort would it not? As I would not get the benefits of automatic client side validation based on the MVC model. I do have in the back of my head that mobile "may" come in to play in the years to come. However, I was planning on opening up a simple api for the very specifics of that. And the api would use the same DLL's as the MVC website.